# Sbt:ResolvedException - Unresolved dependency PlayFramework 2.3.6

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator, typesafe

I'm updating from from play 2.1 to 2.3

Everything works well with the exception of the plugin emailer please see the error console below. Unable to download the plugin play-plugins-mailer for scala version 2.11.1

Please advice on how to go about this

```
"com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1.0"

info] Resolving com.typesafe#play-plugins-mailer_2.11;2.1.0 ...

[warn] ==== Typesafe Repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play-plugins-mailer_2.11/2.1.0/play-plugins-mailer_2.11-2.1.0.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe#play-plugins-mailer_2.11;2.1.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#play-plugins-mailer_2.11;2.1.0: not found
[error] Total time: 14 s, completed Nov 19, 2014 5:04:00 PM

SBT file below

name := """Codi"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
      "org.json" % "json" % "20131018",
      "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "1.7.1",
      "org.apache.directory.studio" % "org.apache.commons.io" % "2.4",
      "org.codehaus.jackson" % "jackson-mapper-asl" % "1.7.7",
      "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.5",
      "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1.0",
      "com.typesafe.play.plugins" %% "play-plugins-util" % "2.3.0",
      "org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.3.2",
    javaCore,
      javaJdbc,
      javaEbean,
      cache,
      javaWs

)


Your help is highly appreciated.

Seroney
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `play-plugins-mailer` plugin is using version 2.1.0, which is not built for Scala 2.11. The newest version is built for 2.11, so you should upgrade:

```
"com.typesafe.play.plugins" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.3.1"
```